# After Ubuntu upgrade, I installed Openshot 2.5.1 and was able to export video to DVD, but when playing the DVD, there is no sound or audio

Tags: upgrade, openshot

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, I found I could not longer create DVD from Openshot Video Editor 2.4.3. A message appears “Sorry there was an error exporting your video: Could not write header to file”.

Prior to that upgrade  Openshot 2.4.3 worked with no errors and I was able to export video to DVD successfully.

I installed Openshot 2.5.1 and was able to export video to DVD, but when playing the DVD, there is no sound or audio. I can’t understand why – as I’m using the same type of imported media that I used before successfully. The 2.5.1 preview plays, of course, as expected with audio.

I checked the sample rate in ‘preferences – profiles’ is the same as sample rate in ‘export – advanced’ , as suggested elsewhere. Here are the export settings

Profile = DVD
Target DVD-PAL
Video Profile = DV/DVD Widescreen PAL
Quality = High
Audio Codec = aac
Sample rate = 48000
Channel layout = Stereo (2 Channel)
Bit rate/Quality 256 kb/s

The only other related issue I can think of is that I tried to uninstall 2.4.3 but got an ‘unmet dependencies’ message. I managed to uninstall it using terminal commands, but the Openshot icon on my Gnome desktop is still there. I don’t think this is a related issue, but I’m throwing it in just in case.

Can someone help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, I looked at the DeVeDeNG debugger and it looked like it was expecting an mp2 codec. I went into Openshot export DVD settings and changed the Audio Codec from aac to mp2. Then I exported the project and ran DeVeDeNG on the .dvd file. After an error message (not the same - I don't think it was related) first time round, I tried again and the job completed successfully. Brasero burned a DVD and the audio came through loud and clear. I don't know why this works now, but hopefully this change might help someone with the same problem.